# Code appended with JQuery does not fire click event on input file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mouseclick-event

I am appending a small block of code that has inside of it an image that when clicked triggers a `click` event on the `input` for file uploading. When the page is loaded and/or refreshed, there is only one block that once changed, fires the event to append  a new one.

```
<div class="add_new_image">
    <div class="img">
        <div class="file-upload-trigger">
            <input type="file" name="imagem[]" class="none file-chooser" required/>
            <img class="more" src="/assets/auto/images/add_image.png"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The JQuery code for appending:

```
$('#novo_anuncio .file-chooser').change(function() {
    readURL(this);
    $('#novo_anuncio .add_new_image').append(
        '<div class="img">\n\
            <div class="file-upload-trigger">\n\
                <input type="file" name="imagem[]" class="none file-chooser" required/>\n\
                <img class="more" src="/assets/auto/images/add_image.png"/>\n\
            </div>\n\
        </div>');
});
```

The problem is that the appended code does not trigger the `click` event on the `input`. The code is identical and it is appended correctly inside of the `.add_new_image` main tag. What could be wrong?

Comment: @charlietfl Yes, that was it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) because when you are binding the "change" listener, your new ".file-chooser" doesn't exist. jQuery on handles all that for you.

> Delegated events have the advantage that they can process events from
>   descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time.

```
$('body').on('change', '#novo_anuncio .file-chooser', function() {
    readURL(this);
    $('#novo_anuncio .add_new_image').append(
        '<div class="img">\n\
            <div class="file-upload-trigger">\n\
                <input type="file" name="imagem[]" class="none file-chooser" required/>\n\
                <img class="more" src="/assets/auto/images/add_image.png"/>\n\
            </div>\n\
        </div>');
});
```

```js
$('body').on('change', '#novo_anuncio .file-chooser', function() {
    alert("change");
    $('#novo_anuncio .add_new_image').append(
        '<div class="img">\n\
            <div class="file-upload-trigger">\n\
                <input type="file" name="imagem[]" class="none file-chooser" required/>\n\
                <img class="more" src="/assets/auto/images/add_image.png"/>\n\
            </div>\n\
        </div>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="novo_anuncio">
  <div class="add_new_image">
    <div class="img">
        <div class="file-upload-trigger">
            <input type="file" name="imagem[]" class="none file-chooser" required/>
            <img class="more" src="/assets/auto/images/add_image.png"/>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, nothing has changed.

Comment: @mfgabriel92 Yes it does, check the code snippet I made you.

Comment: I had to do what you suggested in another part of the code I haven't shown, the code to trigger the event. Thanks.

Comment: Also, the next problem I just had was solved with your solution too. Haha!

Comment: Haha, glad it helped, read about jquery on, and delegated events, It will help you alot!